# rxjs and flowjs - type checking for subscribe function

Tags: flow-typed

Hi I need to type check my emit/subscribe functions from rxjs

my type:

```
type dataType = {|
    name: string,
    lastName: string,
    country: string,
    city: string,
    email: string,
    phone: string,
    comments: string,
  |}
```

my observable:

```
Rx.Observable
  .fromEvent(this.submitEmitter, 'press')
  .throttleTime(1000)
  .subscribe((data: dataType) => this.doSubmit(data))
;
```

my emitter:

```
this.submitEmitter.emit('press', {
  name,
  lastName,
  country,
  city,
  email,
  phone,
  comments,
});
```

if I remove any member from the payload used in the emit function, flowjs doesnt complain about this.